# Making a function that reverses the order of chars in a char array

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I've been really struggling with understanding pointers. My function is supposed to reverse the order of chars, so if w is green it will reverse to neerg. The function I have looks right to me, but its not swapping the chars. Anyone see what's wrong?

```
void mirror(char *w){
    char *p=w;
    while(*p!='\0'){
        p++;
    }
    p--;
    while(*w!='\0'){
        char temp=*p;
        *p=*w;
        *w=temp;
        w++;
        p--;
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the function line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. Add a watch for the string itself, to see how it is modified each iteration. It will very clearly tell you what's wrong.

Comment: You aren't passing a string literal into `mirror` ala `mirror("Hello world");` are you?

Comment: To test it Im using char w[]="Hello"; mirror(w); cout<<w;

Comment: You are doing the swapping in the second loop, but you do a swap for *every* character. That means that first you swap the first with the last character, then you proceed until you finally swap the last character with the first. To do it correctly you have to stop half way through.

Comment: Try to dump the string to terminal in each iteration of the second loop to see what is happening step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while(*w!='\0') {`

You don't want to wait to the end of the string, otherwise, you'll wind up swapping all the characters twice.

Here's a hint.  You want to break when "w" gets ahead of "p".  Let me know if that doesn't make the fix more obvious.

Other bug. Special case the empty string by exiting immediately and before doing pointer math and deferences.

Comment: Got it! Changed loop to while(p>w) so it will break when the addresses are ahead of eachother.

Answer (score 1):

There is one issue in your code. Your code in reversing the string but the final result remains same because your w pointer is moving to end to string length, and it makes your string same.
So solution is that you should change the second while condition :

```
while (w < p)
```

now it will reverse your string.

I already run with this condition and result was right.

See:
[image: Your code Output]

[image]

Comment: @j6t no. Generally it is not https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/4117728. Though, I also do not know why this was downvoted. However, the downvoter may or may not explain. If they do it can end up in a useless fight. If they dont, this comments are futile too.

Comment: @AjayMahiwal do not worry about a single vote. The most emotional votes are the early ones, but the onse that count on the long run are those applied on the long run. Voters are not obliged to explain their vote. If they didnt drop a comment, chances are high that they also will not do it after your request. I think one also has to understand that a single downvote means almost nothing (and I know that sometimes this is not easy)

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are tough, no other way about that. The question has already been answered, however, I think that you could make your task and understanding easier, if you broke down your code a little and named everything according to what they represent. The task gets immediately easier.

As you correctly identified, we need to first measure the length of the array to determine the position of last character in the array.
Lets make a function for that. You can use your approach using `while(*w != '\0')`, or there is std::strlen in  that does the same.

```
char* get_last_char(char* p_first){
    //Here you can use the while approach or cstring's strlen
    size_t char_num = std::strlen(p_first);
    //We get the pointer to the last element
    return p_first+char_num-1;
}
```

Next we need a functionality that will swap two elements, again lets do the function for that.

```
void swap_chars(char *ch1, char *ch2){
    char temp = *ch1;
    *ch1 = *ch2;
    *ch2 = temp;
}
```

this allows me to reduce your mirror code to a very readable:

```
void mirror(char *p_first){
    char *p_last = get_last_char(p_first);
    while(p_last>p_first)
        swap_chars(p_first++,p_last--);
}
```

Simply by naming the pointers in a more descriptive way, and separating the task into elementary steps, my code becomes more readable, despite doing the exactly the same thing.This in turn allows me to avoid the hurdle you ran into. I thought this might be worth sharing.

Comment: the actual issue you do not address in this answer. You should make your answer selfcontained. When you say "this allows me to reduce your mirror code to a very readable:" what follows is not OPs mirror code made readable, but it is OPs mirror code after applying the fix and made more readable

Comment: in other words "....despite doing the exactly the same thing" is not correct and misleading

Answer (score -1):

Just reading the code it looks like you do reverse the string but end up undoing it by the end. You could probably compare if one pointer is greater than other in second loop.